# how to keep a div hovered with css3 animation

Tags: css

How do I keep div expanded as it is hovered(instead if once it s hovered it executes one time and get smaller again) In my case as hover make the box bigger and keep it so, mouseout then bring it small..

Here is my code:

```
.box{width:30px; height:30px; border-radius:100%; margin:200px auto; background:lightblue;}

.box:hover{-webkit-animation:boxes 2s;}

@-webkit-keyframes boxes{
from{width:30px;heigh:30px;}
to{width:200px;height:200px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4S98w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to let the final animation state persist:

```
.box:hover {
    -webkit-animation:boxes 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4S98w/1/

However, if you want the animation to go both ways (i.e. animated enlargement when hovering in, animated shrinking when hovering out), may I suggest using CSS transitions instead?

```
.box {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin:200px auto;
    background:lightblue;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    /* or you can use "transition: all 2s linear:" */
}
.box:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4S98w/2/

Answer (score 1):

js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4S98w/3/

Use css transition :

```
.box{width:30px; height:30px; border-radius:100%; margin:200px auto;background:lightblue;
    transition : width 2s, height 2s;
    -webkit-transition : width 2s, height 2s;
}

.box:hover{    width:200px;height:200px;
    transition : width 2s, height 2s;
    -webkit-transition : width 2s, height 2s;
}
```